# Finding appropriate parameters for Gamma when bootstrapping a GLM

Tags: generalized-linear-model, bootstrap, gamma-distribution

I'll illustrate what I want to do with a Poisson GLM first. I have a GLM with only factor co-variates, thus, to bootstrap this GLM what I can do is e.g. take a single random observation without the response, predict the response using my Poisson GLM, and get a value $\lambda$. Since this is Poisson, the predicted expected value (response) is exactly the same as the parameter I need to for the distribution: I can sample a number from uniform $[0, 1]$ and quantile this number from a $POI(\lambda)$.

Now, is it possible to do this with the Gamma GLM (log-link)? The expected value of a gamma distribution is $\alpha\beta$ or $\frac{\alpha}{\beta}$, depending on your definition. I'm also open to other ideas.

Comment: With a gamma glm the parameterization you would start with a shape-mean parameterization with the glm; the glm gives you the mean and you can then estimate the shape (e.g. in R, the package `MASS` that comes with R provides utilities for exactly this purpose). You can then easily convert to a shape-scale or shape rate parameterization as suits your needs. (In R you'd use `rgamma` to generate random gammas).

Comment: @Glen_b Can you elaborate a bit more? I couldn't find what you mean by a shape-mean parameterization, nor do I know the package that could do so in `MASS`.

Comment: MASS *is* a package. Search for *gamma* in the help file. The mean $\mu$ is shape$\times$scale, you just rewrite the density in terms of $\alpha, \mu$. A search *here* on stats.SE should turn up several hits.

Comment: Specifically, in R, `library(help="MASS")` should give you a window that lists the functions and data sets in MASS (which comes with R). In that list, you should be able to find `gamma.dispersion` and `gamma.shape`. (A   reference for the dispersion-mean form is Dunn & Smyth *Generalized Linear Models With Examples in R*, page 428. The shape mean form simply replaces each $1/\phi$ with $\alpha$. Or take the shape-scale form and replace every occurrence of the scale parameter with $\mu/\alpha$; ... ctd

Comment: ctd... either way should give the same form   as given by Stefan [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/484674/805) (there $\nu$ is the shape)